What's the equivalent of "Resume" icon in Jetpack Compose Material Icons?
I am implementing the extended Material Icons library in my gradle file:
implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.6.8'

Although I can find almost all of the icons, by the same name as they appear on the Google site, I'm not finding the "Resume" icon, as you can see in the image below:

How do I know if this icon is in the library or not? Is it under a different name? If not, how can I find an icon similar to this one?

Are you looking at the right set of icons? The material-icons-extended dependency corresponds with the "Material Icons (deprecated)" set in the Filters of that website.

@ianhanniballake I have searched inside all the sets: AutoMirrored,Default,Filled,Outlined,Rounded,Sharp,TowTone and in none of them does Resume appear.

Again, you aren't even looking at the right style - you are looking through the "Material Symbols (new)" - not the "Material Icons (deprecated)". Resume is not in the Material Icons set.

@ianhanniballake Forgive my ignorance, but I don't understand your comment. What is the way to look at the correct style? Is there a dependency for Material Symbols?

Using the link to the "Resume" icon you posted: In the filter panel on the left scroll down to the section "Style" and switch "Material Symbols (new)" to "Material Icons (deprecated)". What is displayed now are the icons that are included in material-icons-extended. And there is no "Resume" icon: Neither on the website, nor in the library.

@Leviathan Ok, now I understand. I didn't know about this option of the Filter panel on the website.  But if Material Icons is deprecated, is there any dependency for Material Symbols that I can use in Jetpack Compose?

None that I know of.

I checked Google's official document about Icons. They wrote that:

Icons maintain the same names defined by Material, but with their snake_case name converted to PascalCase. For example: add_alarm becomes AddAlarm.

So I think if you couldn't find it in Icons with the name Resume then it means it doesn't exist in this library. There's a Not Started Icon in the library that I found quite similar to the Resume, you can try it. If you still want to use the Resume, just download it
.

That's not really an answer, more like a confirmation. Can you expand your post to actually answer the question?

Thanks for your reminder. I have just edited my answer

You are right, Not Started icon is the same as Resume icon. Thanks!

Glad to hear it helped
